# Opengl - how draw button of any size from tiles using texture atlas

Tags: button, opengl, texture-atlas

I want create buttons of any size using tiles duplication stored in texture atlas. This means, I am going to duplicate some parts of the texture to preserve correct sizes for corners and border lines.

I created square texture as a skin. It's size is 96x96 pixels. You can see it below.

[image]

I split this texture into 9 tiles and I store it in texture atlas. One tile is 32px size.

[image]

Now I duplicate corners and borders to create button

[image]

If I create buttons with size 96px, 128px, 160px, ...etc - everything is fine. No graphic artifacts

If I create button with not standard size (for example 100px) then by placing tiles side by side is at the end created the hole which is not size of tile. For example, if button's size is 100px then I put 3 tiles of 32px side by side and the rest is 4 pixels.

I can resize 32px tile to remaning 4px, but many times I see there graphic artifacts or it looks a bit differently then the other tiles (of course, it is stretched).

Here is the example:

[image]

How to deal with this? Or is this way of making buttons completely wrong?

Comment: If you're going to scale 1 tile, then you'll have to scale each and every tile, otherwise you'll have artifacts. But even if you scale every tile (of course with the same amount/factor) then, due to rounding, visible artifacts can still occur. But still, the 'correct' way to fit your 'button' into a non standard size (not a multiple of the tile extents) would be to calculate the scaling factor and scale every tile by that amount.

Comment: If the previous suggestion does not satisfy you (because, the visible border, radius, etc. would be influenced by the scaling), then you have to find a way to 'fit' only the middle area (leaving the outer tiles untouched). In this way, your 'button' would have a min size, otherwise not possible to render correctly.

Comment: Depending on the visual appereance of your border, you could also do a two pass rendering, where you first render the 'content' and then the 'border'.

Comment: Thank you, at morning I will modify algorithm to first idea and will see. I dont understand the second recommendation. What do you mean with "outer tiles untouched"? They must be resized.

Comment: It is not seen clearly, but background (blue) is half transparent

Comment: Yes, but that also changes the the border size and the radius, right? To avoid that, you could only resize (fit) the content and therefore leave the border untouched. But if there is no issue with that, then there is no problem.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Border size and radius should be not changed. Button supports live resizing. But I will see after implementation. Maybe it will be not so bad. I am still not clear how to fit borders if they dont match tile size. I can resize content, but borders must be resized too, no?

Comment: Then, you can't scale the border tiles. You have to somehow fit the 'content' of the middle area and render the borders as they are. Now, i would suggest, that you first render the content using the border alpha mask to cut out the borders (or via round rect geometry) and then render the border with blending and a blend color (uniform) over the image.

Comment: In that way, the borders are separated from the 'content' and always visibly pleasant. The 'content' can be scaled or cut as needed.

Comment: [9-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-slice_scaling)

Comment: It's a fine way to make buttons, you just have to decide how to do the border. Instead of stretching a tile you could also use part of a tile instead of the whole tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach does have two major issues:

1. if your component (Button) has a size, that is not a multiple of the tile extents, scaling or cutting is unavoidable
2. if you scale the tiles, the radius of the corners and the line thickness of the border will be distorted by the scaling factors

In the comments section above, you mentioned that the border (i assume the radius and the line thickness) should stay intact, no matter the size of the component (Button).

As a solution, i would recommend a two pass rendering:

1. create a 1 component (GL_RED) texture atlas, which functions as an alpha mask for the border
2. render the content area of your Button (i am not sure if you use a single color or a texture as filling, if latter, you'll have to use another texture for that). You have two options on how to cut out the border area:

   - use a round rect geometry (coords and tex coords)
   - use the border alpha mask to discard the specific areas
3. enable blending and render the border. Since the border is specified as an alpha mask, use a uniform to specify the border color (and maybe the opacity, which lets you control the border intensity)

The only downside to this approach is, that your Button will have a minimum size (that would be size of the border: inset left + right and bottom + top).

The upsides are, that your background is independent from the border (and vice versa) and the borders of all your Buttons/Components will have a consistent visual appearance (maybe you want to present more than one Button at a time), no matter of the individual extents.